# Error related to compilation when using install.packages

Tags: r

I am using R 3.3.3 on raspbian. I'm trying to install packages, and most have worked with no problem. However, when I try to install lubridate it fails and I get an extensive error message. The following part caught my attention:

`#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.`

I haven't been able to find how to add these compiler options. Any ideas/support would be appreciated.

Comment: See the `configure.args` argument in `?install.packages`. Try something like `install.packages("lubridate", configure.args = "-std=c++11")`

Comment: I've tried both `install.packages("lubridate", configure.args = "-std=c++11")` and `install.packages("lubridate", configure.args = "-std=gnu++11")` with no success

Comment: If you try g++ -v what do you get? See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93597/problem-with-gcc-g-versions

Comment: Looks like I have gcc version 4.9.2

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update the compiler by running `sudo apt-get install g++`